# Contract-first web services?

Tags: java, web-services

I'm interested in learning more about **contract-first** web services, including how to put them together.

1. Can anyone recommend useful resources that explain the needed aspects/components and how to produce them?
2. Can anyone recommend frameworks in addition to or as an alternative to Spring's contract first web services?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [axis2](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/) for contract first WS development. [This guide is pretty close to how I do it.](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/08/08/contract-first-web-services-with-axis2.html)

1. build a WSDL and schema
2. Run WSDL2Java
3. Build an implementation of the generated skeleton interface

I've also used spring-ws, which I found to be about the same amount of work.

Answer (score 4):

In answwer to 2. Another alternative is CXF. I have a tutorial [here](https://mvnwls.wordpress.com/) for devloping a CXF webservice contract first with maven.

Comment: +1 for an updated answer. CXF builds on top of Spring anyway and seems a [slightly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1245386/1864054) better alternative to Axis.

Comment: That said, [the tutorial](https://mvnwls.wordpress.com/2011/02/01/contract-first-cxf/) you were referring to is outdated too, since it uses pom.xml code that won't build out-of-the-box. This is mainly due to the change [from m2eclipse 0.12 to m2e](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered).

Comment: Among the ones on [Google's 1st page](https://www.google.com/search?q=contract-first+cxf+tutorial), this *Contract First JAX-WS Using Apache CXF* [tutorial](http://pseudoarchitect.wordpress.com/2012/09/22/contract-first-jax-ws-using-apache-cxf/)  seems to offer a better combination of format + freshness. For now.

Answer (score 2):

A framework that is dedicated to contract first web services is [Spring Web Services](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/). I recommend it because of the easiness of integrating web services with large scale applications with the support of the Spring framework.