# Migration guide from Axis2 to CxF

Tags: service, migration, apache-axis, cxf

One of our projects we need to migrate an existing Axis2 - Jax RPC based application to a Apache CxF based runtime.

Has anyone done such migration before...what could be the advantages of CxF over Axis 2?
Is there any migration guide created for reference.

Thanks,
SC

Answer (score 1):

I have used Axis2 and CXF and my choice now goes to CXF because I find it easier to use and also to configure in the pom.xml, especially the wsdl2java plugin.

For a detailed comparison between Axis and CXF check:
[Difference between Apache CXF and Axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243247/difference-between-apache-cxf-and-axis)