# web application creation with apache axis 2 and apache CXF

Tags: web-services, web-applications, apache-axis, cxf

what is the different between apache axis 2 and apache CXF?
And what are the web application fomat of those(war,or jar etc...)

And where can I begin to write a we application with apache CXF?

could u plz define some tutorials to learn this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part, see:

[Difference between Apache CXF and Axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243247/difference-between-apache-cxf-and-axis/1245386#1245386)

For the second question: CXF is very flexible.  You can use a JAR, WAR, OSGi bundle, a "main method" class, Spring context, blueprint, etc....   There are lots of options depending on what works best for you.

There are a lot of tutorials and such at:

http://cxf.apache.org/resources-and-articles.html

to help get you started and there are several example in the CXF download as well.

Comment: Thanks. I want to make apache CXF as a web archive.Not a sample service.just the apache CXF-war.How can I do it? I simply go to the apache CXF binary version folder and type  jar -cvf cxf.war * .Is that correct to deploy to the tomcat server?

Comment: Need a help as soon as possible.