# axis2 versus cxf any recent comparisons?

Tags: web-services

There was a useful thread with SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243247/difference-between-apache-cxf-and-axis), but that was last updated on 2009.  I would like to get the latest comparison between the two.

How about spring-ws?