# How to decide on what framework to use in Java Web Service?(SOAP)

Tags: java, spring, web-services, struts, axis

I am fairly new in Java EE web service. Right now we have a project to create an API web service that connects to a database and do some retrieve and write functions.

I've heard about the following:

- Axis
- Struts
- Spring

Can someone please enlighten me as to what framework is applicable for the said project? I've tried Google of course but I need opinion on people who have experience on the said framework. 
BTW we are going to create a SOAP web service. Additional tips are also appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that Java has the JAX-WS API which is a technology for building web services and clients that communicate using XML. In JAX-WS, a web service operation invocation is represented by an XML-based protocol, such as SOAP.

From the frameworks you mentioned, Spring brings SpringWS which you can use to [build a SOAP web service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/).

However i don't know about Struts 2 core api offering any SOAP capabilities.
But it can be extend with other plugins that handle SOAP.

Axis (use the latest, Axis 2) is a good choice for SOAP. It is a Web Services / SOAP / WSDL engine. It also has some support for the Spring Framework.

There is also Apache CXF. It is the most widely used Web Services Standard Now; Improvement over AXIS2, which is now gradually being replaced by Apache CXF

If you need help deciding between them, read [this comparison (Apache CXF vs. Apache AXIS vs. Spring WS)](https://dzone.com/articles/apache-cxf-vs-apache-axis-vs) for the pros and cons.

There's also [this great answer about cxf and axis 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14933562/4807777).

Comment: Thank you so much! Very detailed answer. +1

Comment: You are welcome! If you feel it answered your question your may mark the answer as accepted.